# How to get data of particular product using its id using angular 2

Tags: angular

I want to extract the detail of particular product using it's id. below is my code:-

This is function i have created inside hero service component. I have checked and all the things are working no errors any where. Value of id is coming fine but how to fetch detail of that particular product using id. I am using observable here.

```
getParticularHero(id: number): Observable<Hero> {
    // Todo: send the message _after_ fetching the hero
    return this.http.get<Hero>(`assets/api/mock-heroes.json/${id}`);
  }
```

//this is the function i have created inside here detail component

```
getHero(): void {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.heroService.getParticularHero(id)
      .subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero);
  }
//Here is my json file
[
  { "id": "11", "name": "Mr. Nice" },
  { "id": "12", "name": "Narco" },
  { "id": "13", "name": "Bombasto" },
  { "id": "20", "name": "Tornado" }
]
```

Comment: Do you mean to say you want to find the data in your json file?

Comment: @ Manzur - Yes, suppose if i click on id 11 in my product detail component then i get the data of that id. i.e. Name and Id.

Comment: What does `assets/api/mock-heroes.json/${id}` return ?

Comment: @Safiyya - It just return a string like this, suppose if i click on id 12 in my detail component - assets/api/mock-heroes.json/12. Which show errors 404 not found in F12 on google chrome console. I was trying this to get detail.

Comment: Unless you defined a api route in your backend, `assets/api/mock-heroes.json/${id}` doesnt exist and you will get a 404. What you can do is modify `getParticularHero` so that it makes a call to `assets/api/mock-heroes.json` and then filter the JSON result by the ID that you want

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the find function javascript provides

```
selectProduct(id) {
   const selectedProduct = this.hero.find(product => product.id === id)
}
```

I assume you must be using an ngFor in your html, call this function passing your id and you will have the product inside selectedProduct

Comment: @ Manzur Khan -  I am using service which returns observable. if i applied find on on that it shows errors find doesn't exist on type <Hero[]>

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `filter` method to filter the IDs that you want from the Observable, here is a complete solution :

**hero.service.ts**

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';

getParticularHero(id: number): Observable<Hero> {
    // Todo: send the message _after_ fetching the hero
    return this.http.get<Hero[]>(`assets/api/mock-heroes.json`).filter(h => h.id === id);
  }
```

where `assets/api/mock-heroes.json` returns

```
[
  { "id": "11", "name": "Mr. Nice" },
  { "id": "12", "name": "Narco" },
  { "id": "13", "name": "Bombasto" },
  { "id": "20", "name": "Tornado" }
]
```

**component.ts**

```
hero : Observable<Hero>

constructor(private service:HeroService)

ngOnInit(){
    let id = // get ID here from route snapshot
    this.hero = this.service.getParticularHero(id)
}
```

**component.html**

```
<!-- Use the async pipe to retrieve the latest value of the Observable --> 
<div>{{(hero | async).name}}</div>
```

Comment: I applied the same it shows the following error - Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Observable<Hero[]>'.

Comment: you have to import the filter operator, i update my answer

Comment: @ Safiyya - I have tried this as well. Now, no errors are coming but it is not showing any product detail.                                                                          return this.http.get<Hero>(this.heroesUrl).filter(h => h.id === id);

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not showing any product detail" ? Could you share the relevant part of your component and HTML ?

Comment: @ Safiyya - ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getHero();
      }
      getHero(): void {
        const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
        this.heroService.getHero(id)
          .subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero);   
      }                                                                                                 
<div *ngIf="hero"> 
<h2>{{ hero.name | uppercase }} Details</h2>
<div><span>id: </span>{{hero.id}}</div>
<div>
  <label>name:
    <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name">
  </label>
  <button (click)="goBack()">go back</button>
</div>

Comment: You can read about how to display Observable values in a HTML template here https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/pipes/async-pipe/. I update my answer.